# remove pattern with variable numbers

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with 1056 columns in which every column looks like this (this is a subset of 4 columns):

```
 0|0:0.2   0|0:0.03   0|0:0.02   0|0:0
 0|0:0.04  0|0:0.7    0|0:0.05   0|0:1.3
```

I would like to remove the double dot and number part from each column and each line.

I've tried this code just for one column, but it is actually not working...

```
awk '{gsub(":[0-9]","",$1)}' file > file.mod
```

I would like that my output file looked like this:

```
0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0
0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0
```

Thank you very much in advanced :)

Comment: `sed 's/:[0-9.]*//g' file`

Comment: You probably wanted to write something like `awk '{gsub(":[0-9.]*",""); print}'`.

Comment: or `sed -E 's/:[^[:blank:]]+//g'` which I think is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Input_file is same as shown samples then could you please try following.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/:.*/,"",$i)}} 1' Input_file
```

Or adding solution from @Socowi comments as follows too.

```
awk '{gsub(":[0-9.]*",""); print}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Socowi, Thanks for nice solution. If you don't mind, I have added your comment's solution too here, please feel free to let me know if you want to post it as an answer too.

Comment: Thanks you very much @RavinderSingh13 and Socowi, both solutions work perfectly :)

Comment: @SoniaOlaecheaLázaro, your welcome,give it sometime when you see all answers are there then try to select one of them as a correct answer too, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl also

```
$ cat sonia.txt
 0|0:0.2   0|0:0.03   0|0:0.02   0|0:0
 0|0:0.04  0|0:0.7    0|0:0.05   0|0:1.3

$ perl -pe ' s/:\S+//g ' sonia.txt
 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0
 0|0  0|0    0|0   0|0

$
```